# How do I learn the methods that can be accessed for certain objects?

Tags: magento

I have the following code:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')  
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'status'), 'inner')  
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid)); 
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
    echo $_product->getProductUrl();
endforeach
```

I want to learn how I discover the methods I can use on an object.

For example $_product->getProductUrl() is using the method getProductUrl() to get the url, but I need price and have no idea what method calls that. Using a print_r doesn't provide enough info for me to discover what they are. I presume they are in controllers that are located in the MAGE core. I have commerce bug and I have tired looking at: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/
But I find myself lost at times.

Does anyone know a good tutorial on this or can give me direction to figuring this out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, in models and blocks, any method with `get` or a `set` **may** actually be a magic method that's pulling from the object's `_data` array.  You can see all the data in an object like this

```
var_dump($object->getData());
```

So if this array had a key named `some_data`, you could call a method named `getSomeData`

```
echo $object->getSomeData();
```

Remember though, some methods will have **actual** methods that start with `get` and `set`, so always check the class definition.

Secondly, you can use PHP reflection functions (or the more complete but complicated PHP Reflection Class API) to see what class an object is, and then get a list of methods on that class

First, use [get_class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to get the name of an object's class.

```
$class_name = get_class($object);
```

Then, pass that [get_class_methods](https://www.php.net/get_class_methods) to get a list of all the callable methods on an object

```
$class_name = get_class($object);
$methods = get_class_methods($class_name);
echo "Methods for class $class_name \n<br />\n";
foreach($methods as $method)
{
    var_dump($method);
}
```

This will give you a list of all the class methods.  You can then use the [Class/URI Lookup](http://commercebugdemo.alanstorm.com/) tab of Commercebug bug to quickly zero in on which file a class is defined in to look at the method definitions.  Remember, some methods will be defined in ancestor classes.  Investing the time to learn an IDE or [a program like ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) is well worth the investment, ad they'll let you quickly jump to individual class definitions.

Comment: +1 for learning to use a proper IDE (I prefer Netbeans), it will help you understand the OO design of Magento infinitely quicker than hacking around in a "dumb" text editor, **especially** when combined with live debugging with xdebug.

Comment: +1 for IDE as well, the deep object hierarchy of Magento makes navigating class inheritance via printed output a thankless task. If you're on a Magento project then you're really on Zend Framework so Zend_Debug::dump($object->getData()); is also [your friend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.debug.dumping.html).

Comment: you can just print_r(get_class_methods($object))

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple direction to find the class files:-

**1. Collection**

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
```

The above code means that we are calling the product collection class. The class file can be found in:-

> app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Product\Collection.php

In Collection.php you will find the following class:-

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
```

So, your required function can be in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection` class.

If it is not there then it can be in the parent class, i.e. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract`

**2. Model**

Similarly,

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
```

For the above code, the class file is:-

> app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php

**3. Helper**

For helper file,

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

The above helper file is:-

> app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Output.php

**4. Finally**

Finally, using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans will help you learn and write code quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total novice, but I used the info on this page to get all the methods available to me for a certain object and send them to a log.

For example the category_collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');


    Mage::log(
            "Methods for class ".get_class($collection)." ".print_r(get_class_methods($menu),true),
            null,
            'log_name.log'
            );

    $parent = get_parent_class($collection);

    while ($parent) {
        Mage::log(
            "Methods for parent ".$parent." ".print_r(get_class_methods($parent),true),
            null,
            'log_name.log'
            ); 
            $parent = get_parent_class($parent);   
    }
```