# How to update an attribute value in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've created an attribute called "popularity" which will be used to organize the catalog by most viewed products. The idea is get its value on product view template (view.phtml on my theme) and increment that value and update it, however I don't know how to make this update, I mean, how to save the new value incremented into database. I've put this on the product view page, take a look:

```
$popularity = $_product->getData('popularity');
$popularity++;
```

The point is that $popularity is not being saved with the new value into database. How can I save that value?

I put the code below on product page template (mytheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml) but is not working:

```
$from_date = '2010-01-01';
$to_date = now();
$product_ids = $_product->getId();
$viewed = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addViewsCount($from_date, $to_date)->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $product_ids);
foreach($viewed as $view) {
    $count_views = $view->getData('views');
    $product_model->setData('popularity', $count_views)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product_model, $count_views); 
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999439/updating-magento-attribute-programatically

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$popularity = $_product->getData('popularity');
$popularity++;
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes(array($_product->getId()), array('popularity', $popularity), 0);
```

This will work, if the scope of your attribute is `GLOBAL`. If it's something else then you can use this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
        ->updateAttributes(
             array($_product->getId()), 
             array('popularity', $popularity), 
             Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
);
```

Comment: I put this code on product page template (mytheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml): `$from_date = '2010-01-01';
$to_date = now();
$product_ids = $_product->getId();
$viewed = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addViewsCount($from_date, $to_date)->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $product_ids);
foreach($viewed as $view) {
 $count_views = $view->getData('views');
    $product_model->setData('popularity', $count_views)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product_model, $count_views);
}` but is not working. :(

Comment: @joaosvu please edit your original question to add the code, as a comment it is not readable. thank you.